# Oracle: earliest date of stay (two columns)

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

i have three columns `id_user, date_stay_start, date_stay_stop` and I need to return complete date of the first stay (the oldest).

I am currently have something like this:

```
SELECT users.id_user, Min(orders.date_stay_start), Min(orders.date_stay_stop)
FROM users
JOIN orders ON users.id_user=orders.id_user
WHERE orders.date_stay_start IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY users.id_user;
```

But there is a problem. If I have two orders from one customer like this:

- first order 02/Jun/2014 (date_stay_start) 10/Jun/2014
  (date_stay_stop) and
- second order 04/Jun/2014 (date_stay_start) 8/Jun/2014
  (date_stay_stop).

The returned result will contain 02/Jun/2014 (date_stay_start) and 8/Jun/2014 (date_stay_stop).

But it should be 02/Jun/2014 (date_stay_start) 10/Jun/2014 (date_stay_stop).

I am using Oracle 11g. Thank you for any advice.

Comment: You either need to group by orders.orderID, or you need to write a subquery to get the earliest order for each user and join it back into the set to limit to that earliest entry.

Comment: OR use a union where all the dates are in the same position of the select list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this may work...

```
SELECT users.id_user, orders.date_stay_start, orders.date_stay_stop
FROM users
JOIN orders 
  ON users.id_user=orders.id_user
INNER JOIN (Select Min(Orders.date_Stay_start) DSS, id_user from orders group by ID_user) o
  ON O.DSS = orders.date_stay_start
 and O.id_user = orders.Id_user
WHERE orders.date_stay_start IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY users.id_user;
```

Comment: Does this work if the same user make several orders having the same `date_stay_start` ? Seems a plausible corner case (travel agency, corporate/familly event, ...)

Comment: assuming time is part of stay start and time is unique yes. The question becomes if they have the same date_stay_start, how do you define the record you want? as all 3 are tied on "MIN"...

Answer (score 0):

Or you can do something like this

```
select * from (
  SELECT u.id_user
    ,o.date_stay_start
    ,o.date_stay_stop
    ,row_number() over (partition by u.id_user order by o.date_stay_start) rn
  FROM users u
  JOIN orders o
    ON u.id_user = o.id_user
  WHERE o.date_stay_start IS NOT NULL
) where rn = 1;
```